# C# insert text after each occurence of a text string using wildcards

Tags: c#, string, replace, wildcard, delimiter

Solved:
This solution has been solved.  I was modding a game and am creating a C# windows form to easily manipulate large quantities of repeating data, or expressions, and quickly insert mass changes to a file, or files.  I was stuck on identifying a regular expression with Regex in my data files and inserting a text box field of data right after the expression I identified.  The expression I have works in the regex editor, thanks to @Kris, but when I deployed it into my program, nothing happened.  I apologize for not having my thoughts in order, I will be sure to be more clear next time I use SO.

Below is the data I wanted to manipulate, followed by the working code I was able to fix myself with pointers from @Kris and @Rufus L.  Again, I needed to search for particular data strings and insert a new string underneath the data property in every occurrence in the file.  Hope this helps someone.

The data properties text looks like this:

```
1234 = {
    workers = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 37800
    }
    professionals = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 6000
    }
    leaders = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 500
    }
}
1235 = {
    workers = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 37800
    }
    professionals = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 6000
    }
    leaders = { 
        culture = dudes
        religion = awesome
        size = 500
    }
}
```

I only want to insert text into the parent #### = {} property that holds the child = {} property fields.  IE, I want to insert textBox2.Text in a new line under 1234 = {

I have the regex expression linked on [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28.*%3F%29%7B&i=1234%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20workers%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%2037800%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20professionals%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%206000%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20leaders%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20500%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A1235%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20workers%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%2037800%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20professionals%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%206000%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20leaders%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20500%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&o=ixm), thanks to @Kris.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        static string[] files;
        static int curNum = 0;
        static string[] txtFiles;
        static string[] provinces;
        public Form1() {
                InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathText.Text + txtFiles[curNum], richTextBox1.Text);
        }
        private void prevButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(curNum > 0)
            curNum--;
            richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathText.Text + txtFiles[curNum]);
            filenameLabel.Text = txtFiles[curNum];
        }
        private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            curNum = 0;
            txtFiles = GetFileNames(pathText.Text, "*.txt");
            richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathText.Text + txtFiles[curNum]);
            filenameLabel.Text = txtFiles[curNum];
        }
        static string[] GetFileNames(string path, string filter) {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(path, filter);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
            return files;
        }
        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(curNum < txtFiles.Length)
            curNum++;
            richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathText.Text + txtFiles[curNum]);
            filenameLabel.Text = txtFiles[curNum];
        }
        private void appendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        provinces = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"\d+(.*?){")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < provinces.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(provinces[i], provinces[i] + System.Environment.NewLine + "    " + textBox2.Text);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Where is your code? A vague description of your code is not helpful. What is the *specific* problem that you're encountering?

Comment: Why does this sound like a homework question, yet again! Do you know anything about objects or in general, anything about collections?

Comment: Description is very descriptive.  If you do not understand, then do not down vote, just ignore it.

Comment: Please show what you have so far, so people can help correct it

Comment: @TGarrett.  I am modding Victoria 2 and am creating a custom windows form that will allow me to take my modified properties and apply them to every province in my file.  Thanks for presuming I am doing college homework.  And yes, I know a lot about objects and collections.

Comment: @stu If you're refusing to add your code, show any effort and ask a specific question then you're not going to get any help. Simply insisting that your question is good enough when there's several people telling you otherwise is not productive.

Comment: I was trying to format it into stack, patience.....I wasn't withholding.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Now, what is the specific problem that you're encountering and what is your question? Currently you have a very vague/unclear description of what you're trying to do and that it "doesn't work".

Comment: the append button will execute my replace, but I don't know how to use wildcards for numbers and -= { with the replace feature.

Comment: The code you have presented just shows you have the ability to read & write files - there appears to be no attempt to solve your own problem. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you looked into using regular expressions?

Comment: `I don't know how to use wildcards` is not something we can help with. Go do some research and write some code that's relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: I got what I needed. I will update the code. @Kris sent me a link for a regex tester.  I just needed the proper regular expression to insert in my string replacement.

Comment: @stu Wow, you really need to improve how you ask questions. Please show effort first and be more clear about the problem at hand. There's so much irrelevant information and code here.

Comment: I updated the problem to be more clear, and I have a somewhat working code, but the append button doesn't apply my Regex.replace properly.

Comment: So currently, I am successfully scanning my loaded text file in the richTextBox1.Text property and changing the values to what I want, but I am having problems writing those changes back into the richTextBox1.Text.

Comment: Fixed it.  I no longer require assistance.  I was able to insert the text as desired.  I want to thank Kris and Rufus for pointing out a few tid bits to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex

> \d+(.*?){

[tested here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28.*%3F%29%7B&i=1234%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20workers%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%2037800%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20professionals%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%206000%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20leaders%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20500%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A1235%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20workers%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%2037800%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20professionals%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%206000%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20leaders%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20culture%20%3D%20dudes%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20religion%20%3D%20awesome%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20size%20%3D%20500%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&o=ixm)

Comment: this is genious, thanks for the regex tester link!!!

Comment: I was able to get it sorted.  I want to thank you for pointing out the Regex tester.  This really really helped me beyond anything you could know.  I credited you with the save on this one because initially I wanted help with the detection of wildcards, and you more than came through.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to insert the text at the end of each block, by searching for two `}` characters separated by `0` or more whitespace characters. The regex for this would look like:

```
Regex.Matches(searchString, "}\\s}");
```

In either case, when inserting the strings we should start from the *last* match (at the end of the string) and move backwards towards the beginning, because each insert will change the string length and therefore impact the index at which we want to do the insertion.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a string with newText inserted into parentText
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newText">The new text to insert</param>
/// <param name="parentText">The parent text to insert into</param>
/// <returns>The parent string with the newText inserted</returns>
private string GetInsertedText(string newText, string parentText)
{
    var newParentText = parentText;
    var matches = Regex.Matches(newParentText, "}\\s}");

    // Replace from the last occurrence, since each insert will 
    // change the length of our string and alter the insert location
    for(int index = matches.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        var match = matches[index];

        newParentText = newParentText.Substring(0, match.Index + 1) + 
            Environment.NewLine + newText +
            newParentText.Substring(match.Index + 1);
    }

    return newParentText;
}
```

You also might want to create a method that adds 4 spaces to the beginning of each line of the `textBox1.Text` so that it has a proper indent after it's inserted. For example:

```
private string GetIndentedText(string originalText, string indentText = "    ")
{
    return $"{indentText}{originalText}".Replace("\n", $"\n{indentText}").TrimEnd();
}
```

The usage of this would look something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check for any text requirements here (like it should contain
    // an open brace, an equals sign, end with a close brace, etc.)
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        // Insert the new (indented) text into our RichTextBox
        richTextBox1.Text = GetInsertedText(GetIndentedText(textBox1.Text), 
            richTextBox1.Text);

        // Clear the input textbox
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using the ending braces like you suggested, but the properties can scope out more than one level of detail, IE, it is possible to have more than one set of trailing double braces in any given file or parent property.  The example I gave and the game files don't seem to make use of that practice, but the province number ID property is used elsewhere in the game's files, and I would like to be able to identify any instance of a numeric text string making use of the = {} to identify via code that I am working with a province property, or scope.  Thanks for the reply, it does help.

Comment: I ended up using Regex.Matches to find the specific string I was looking for.  Your code was genious, but I really needed to be able to sniff out the numbers in this case.  Thank you for setting that suggestion up for me, it really helped me get my string detection in order.